# Parse Json Twitter search

Tags: c#, silverlight, api, windows-phone-7, twitter

I'm trying to Parse Json search results from twitter and I am using JArray.

The problem is this, I can parse someones username and the results will display, however, when I try to parse the search API nothing displays. Here is my code:

```
private void twitterClient()
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadStringCompleted);

    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=twitter&rpp=5&include_entities=true&result_type=mixed"));
}

void DownloadStringCompleted(object senders, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try {

       JArray twitterContent = JArray.Parse(e.Result);

    }catch(Exception twit_error)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Cannot parse"); 
    }
 }
```

As you can see, the URL exists, and, if I change the url from search to someones username, it will parse and display these results.

Hope someone can help me or offer some advice.

Comment: Assume that you are using JSON.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON returned by the provided URI is not an array, it's an object. Therefore wouldn't

```
JObject.Parse
```

be more appropriate?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that seems to have solved the error of Parsing, however, can I still "treat" it as an Array? in that, can I still use: `ja[count]["user"]["profile_image_url"].ToString();` or is there a different structure now?